# I just bought Pokemon Platinum, my brother got Diamond. Can we catch them all?

Tags: pokemon-series

Or will we need someone with Pearl?

If we did have Pearl/Diamond/Platinum, which Pokemon would we still not be able to get?

I want to catch them all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Platinum_Version#Missing_Pok.C3.A9mon), you'll need Pearl to get Misdreavus (-> Mismagius) and Glameow (-> Purugly).

Comment: This discounts legendary event pokemon, and pokemon from the other regions. Otherwise, I think this is correct.

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily need to find and talk to a person with Pearl to get these - eventually, you will see these Pokémon from in-game trainers, and you'll then be able to use the GTS to trade for them (if you can find anyone wanting to make a reasonable trade, that is).

Comment: @michaelmadsen GTS?

Comment: @Ryan: Yeah, sorry, should have explained what that was. The GTS is the [Global Trade Station](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/GTS#Global_Trade_Station), located in Jubilife City (one of the first cities you visit). There, you can trade with people from around the world without ever having met them. Pokémon Platinum replaced it with the Global Terminal, which adds some more features.